# Swift replace full line in String

Tags: swift

I have multiple lines in an String, for example:

```
let str = "Mieter: Hannes Tester \nVerwalter: Michael Karner \n"
```

Now i want to remove the whole sentence between "Mieter" and the line break. So the result should be:

```
let str = "Verwalter: Michael Karner \n"
```

I could check with Regex, but i am only able to get the string between 2 words. For example with:

```
if let match = str.rangeOfString("(?<=Mieter)[^\n]+", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
    print(str.substringWithRange(match)) // between
}
```

But how can i replace a whole line?

**Edit:**

It is not working anymore when its between a string:

```
let str = "Test \n Mieter: \n Hausverwalter: \n Firma: \n"

str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("^Mieter[^\n]+\\s", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)

// so "Mieter \n" is not being replaced.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `replacingOccurrencesOf`

```
let str = "Mieter: Hannes Tester \nVerwalter: Michael Karner \n"
str.replacingOccurrences(of: "^Mieter[^\n]+\\s", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

This is Swift 3 code

**Edit:**

If the substring is not at the beginning of the string remove the leading caret (`^`).

Comment: Thanks. Do you have it for Swift 2.3 too? Its not: str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("^Mieter[^\n]+\\s", withString: "")

Comment: Ok found it: str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("^Mieter[^\n]+\\s", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)

Comment: Please use code completion, `stringByReplacing...` is probably correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have still a problem, its not working anymore if its between a string - can u help me again please? (see my Edit)

Comment: Remove the leading caret `^` in the regex pattern